# How to display real-time push messages on Kendo UI mobile ListView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm able to display real time push messages from **[RabbitMQ SockJS Server](http://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html)** on a browser using JQuery append whenever a new message arrives.  However, I'm not able to figure out how to display the messages on Kendo UI mobile ListView (Kendo version 2013.3.1119) in descending order - newer messages at the top.  This should be done without the user intervening to refresh the ListView.

I've created a test and posted on JSBin - **[link](http://jsbin.com/onopERIr/1/edit?html,output)**

Notes on JSBin example:

1). Stomp.js (**[STOMP over websocket](http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/)**) and sockjs.js (**[SockJS Javascript client](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client)**) is used to create the websocket client that captures messages from RabbitMQ SockJS Server.

For the JSBin example, I've appended my Javascript code that works with STOMP (listener-app.js - see - **http://pastebin.com/6qLxH8R6**) into the SockJS Javascript client (sockjs.js) as I'm not able to get the JSBin to work with listener-app.js in a separate file.  The combined script is now stomp-listener-app.js.  A note that I didn't have this problem when testing locally.

2). There are 2 nav buttons, "Real-time ListView" and "Debug Log".  Debug Log captures stomp.js debug messages which will be displayed on "Debug Log" view using JQuery append.  Real-time ListView view is suppose to display the STOMP messages in a listview - for which I'm unable to do so.

3). Although the JSBin example doesn't link to a live SockJS server, the STOMP library will still generate some error messages which can be captured by Kendo UI.

I'm a beginner in JS and Kendo UI.  Please let me know if I had missed out anything.  Any pointer will be very much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: suggestion: try to isolate the main problem to reduce the complexity of the question - e.g. remove RabbitMQ etc. from the equation and create a sample that only uses a ListView and setInterval for timed updates; this will increase your chances of getting an answer

Comment: @LarsHöppner Thanks, what you've said is correct.  When posting the question, I didn't quite understand how functions and libraries are shared across separate Javascript files, that's why I posted the RabbitMQ code.  Now I know that it is possible to use functions across on Javascript files without changes or declaring it in the file it is to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I can use the [prepend/append method](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/listview#methods-prepend) to insert new messages at the top of the listview.

For example:

```
$("#datalistlistView").data("kendoMobileListView").prepend([{message: 'test'}]);
```

This code can be inserted into any JS file linked from the html page.

The key requirement is that the code must run only after the listview is initialized, otherwise a *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'prepend' of null"* error will appear.